# Modsecurity...Host header is a numeric IP address Cannot serve directory no matching directoryindex

Tags: apache2, mod-security, debian-stretch

my system is
Debian 9
Apache2
php-fpm

i am experiencing an error with one of the websites on my webserver.

I have tried adding an index.html file into the public_html directory (and disabling htaccess and wordpress index.php), however it appears to be trapping before the virtual host is serving the page.

i found the following in apache2 log for the virtual host where this is a problem.

It is also supposed to be the default domain for the host system ipaddress.

> [Fri May 08 08:38:55.023689 2020] [:error] [pid 16874:tid 139899541833472] [client 12.34.56.78:46780] [client 12.34.56.78] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match “^[\d.:]+$” at REQUEST_HEADERS:Host. [file “/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf”] [line “793”] [id “920350”] [rev “2”] [msg “Host header is a numeric IP address”] [data “12.34.56.78:443”] [severity “WARNING”] [ver “OWASP_CRS/3.0.0”] [maturity “9”] [accuracy “9”] [tag “application-multi”] [tag “language-multi”] [tag “platform-multi”] [tag “attack-protocol”] [tag “OWASP_CRS/PROTOCOL_VIOLATION/IP_HOST”] [tag “WASCTC/WASC-21”] [tag “OWASP_TOP_10/A7”] [tag “PCI/6.5.10”] [hostname “12.34.56.78”] [uri “/”] [unique_id “XrSN-2ic6bwAAEHqQ4oAAABW”]
>   [Fri May 08 08:38:55.024469 2020] [autoindex:error] [pid 16874:tid 139899541833472] [client 12.34.56.78:46780] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/tesla/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.htm,index.php,index.php4,index.php5) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

*(i have substituted tesla for my domain name)*

I am not sure what to do to fix this?

Comment: "host header" is a warning.  "Cannot serve", if you did indeed put an index.html file in /home/tesla/public_html, then Apache may not have the necessary access rights to that file or directory.  But Apache says that the file just isn't there.  I put a lot of trust in Apache.

Comment: what about the warning `msg “Host header is a numeric IP address"`? Clearly that is triggering a modsecurity action

Comment: If it's so clear: which one?

Comment: It's hard to see in your question, but there are two different error messages.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille: the [id “920350”] shows to you which rule matches. The message comes by the action 'msg:....' but there isn't any disruptive action.

Comment: @adam: I think the problem is you don't have any virtualhost config.

Comment: @airween  thanks for telling me what I knew.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - sorry, I undesrstood from the comments above that's not clear. Sorry again.

Comment: @airween, no problem, we're good. I believe we both agree that the first message is just a warning and the second one a real error.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille - thanks. Yeah', absolutely :).